# How to alter level 3 meaning of keys with XKB

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, xmodmap, sway

I had a neat little hack to get German "Umlaute" on a US ANSI keyboard with XModap. When I hold Caps-Lock, I get Umlaute in the places where they are on a German keyboard. Here my .Xmodmap file

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keycode  66 = Mode_switch

keycode  26 = e E EuroSign cent
keycode  30 = u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keycode  34 = bracketleft braceleft udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keycode  47 = semicolon colon odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keycode  32 = o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keycode  48 = apostrophe quotedbl adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keycode  38 = a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keycode  20 = minus underscore ssharp ssharp
keycode  39 = s S ssharp
keycode 106 = Shift_R
```

Ever since I switched to Wayland/sway this does not work any more and I currently only see the option to do this in XKB. I could not figure out:

- how do I make Caps-Lock not "sticky"?
- how do I add the needed Level 3 to a given key?

Comment: first, try an international variant of the `us` layout (`intl`, `alt-intl` or `altgr-intl`).  these will include common international symbols on lvl3 of alphabetic keys.  second, set option `lv3:caps_switch` to set capslock to `ISO_Level3_Shift`.  you may also want a Compose key to access compose sequences (eg option `compose:menu`).  the international layouts will differ from your xmodmap, but are fairly standard in most XKB environments.  see `man xkeyboard-config` for a list of layouts, variants and options.

Comment: I will probably give that a try. At work I am stuck with windows anyway and it seems the "US International" bevaves the same as alt-intl, at least for the German special characters